# Javascript (ES6) Set values to plain Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, set

How to transform the values of Javascript ES6 Set wrapper into a plain Object? Especially: What is the fastest/shortest way to do so?

I am looking for something like the following that applies to Arrays:

```
const myArray = Array.from(mySet);
```

I tried in vain:

```
// mySet variable is Set containing integers {1, 2, 3, ..., n}

Object.assign({}, mySet);
Object.assign({}, mySet.values());
Object.assign({}, mySet.entries());
```

Finally, I am thinking about creating a new object, iterating over the set and pushing its entries into the new object. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do so.

Comment: What do you want as output ?

Comment: `const myObject = {1, 2, 3, ..., n};`

Comment: But it's not a valid object

Comment: Damn. It is true. So I have to stick to array, I suppose.

Comment: `Object.assign( {}, [ ...mySet ])`

Comment: As pawel pointed out, a valid output would be `{ 1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 3 }` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929988/javascript-es6-set-values-to-plain-object#comment80807342_46930131

Comment: @Samuel that's what my code from earlier comment returns.

Comment: @pawel It returns {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, not { 1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 3 }

Comment: @Faly well yeah, of course it does, sorry. Iterating over the elements may be the only way after all. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Use ES6 spread syntax:

```js
var mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
var myArray = [ ...mySet];
console.log(myArray);
```

EDIT: To get an object instead of an array, it should be:

```js
var mySet = new Set([1, 2, 3]);
var obj = {};
[ ...mySet].forEach(el => obj[el] = el);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: So you have basically reiterated the "I know how to convert Set into Array" part of the question?

Comment: @pawel The object he want is not valid: { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

Comment: Since he asks for an object I'd assume the expected results would be `{ 1 : 1, 2 : 2, 3 : 3 }`

Comment: It's ok. I will modify my question slightly. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) returns an [Interactor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) and objects don't technically exist without keys. You would need to assign a key for each value and the simplest way of doing that is to spread it into a new array, so that the index of the array becomes the key.

```
// returns { "0": 1, "1": 2, "2": 3, ..., "i": n }
{...{}, ...[...mySet]};

// Same as above.
Object.assign({}, Array.from(mySet));
```

If however, you want the key and value to be the same in the object, you can run a [reducer method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the parsed array, with the initial value as the returned object.

```
const myReducer = (acc, cur) => {
  // You don't need to stringify, if you can ensure it's always numbers.
  acc[JSON.stringify(cur)] = cur;
  return acc;
};

// Returns { "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, ..., "n": n }
Array.from(mySet).reduce(myReducer, {});

// One liner, as per above, just less readable.
[...mySet].reduce((acc, cur) => !(acc[JSON.stringiy(cur)] = cur) || acc, {});
```

**Disclaimer:** As [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) can have any primitive value, at any location, the keys can get a bit crazy when assigning objects to it.

```
// Returns { "1": 1, "{\"test1\":1}": { "test1": 1 } }
[...new Set([1, {test1:1}])].reduce(myReducer, {});
```